# Zoom camera in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

I want to zoom in when user click on marker.I tried using-

```
 googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker)
                {
                  googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(3));
                    slidingPaneLayout.setPanelHeight(700);





            });
```

I also tried

```
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
```

but its not zooming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the click event on the Marker is conflicting with the zooming animation. You can try adding a timeout:

```
 import android.os.Handler;

 Handler handler = new Handler();
 googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker)
            {
              handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(3));
              }, 200);
              return true;
            });
```

This would delay the execution of the animation call by 200ms. Also make sure to return `true` as this indicates that you have consumed the event (See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html)). Haven't tried it but this might work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code into your `marker onclick event`

```
{LatLng yournewposition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder()
                    .target(yournewposition).zoom(10).build();
            yourmapobject.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));}
```

-THanks.!